# How to link to static resources if I change router.base in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

By default, I can use static resources like this in Nuxtjs pages:

```html
<img src="/img/logo.jpg"/>
...
<style>
.my-class {
  background-image: url("/img/background.jpg");
}
</style>
```

which `/img/logo.jpg` and `/img/background.jpg` are under `<project>/static/` directory, and the page `http://localhost:3000/some-page` can be rendered correctly.

But, if I set `router.base` to a subpath like this:

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/demo',
  }
}
```

The url of the page will be changed to `http://localhost:3000/demo/some-page`, but the image url is not changed: `http://localhost:3000/img/logo.jpg`.

Should I hard code the subpath before each resource link? why nuxtjs won't change the static resources automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer, it's impossible to automatically add a prefix before `img.src` or `css.url`, because those tags might be dynamically set by data binding, and the Nuxt or Vue-router couldn't change those paths at runtime.

If I use `<nuxt-link>` or `<router-link>` tag to set up a link, the path will be automatically added by `base` option, but if I use `<a>` it will not, that's correct.

So, I think the best answer is to set a global variable that represents the `base` value, and use it like this:

```
<img :src="`${BASE}/img/logo.jpg`">
```

Answer (score 0):

use $router.options.base as a computed and use it.